# Receiving an error when running ggsurvplot

Tags: r

I am trying to run a survival analysis and then create a kaplan meier curve using the ggsurvplot function. However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 0, 8...`
```

Does anyone know where I may be going wrong? Thank you!!!

```
`MRE_time <- as.numeric(c(10, 20, 15, 30))
MRE_status <- as.factor(c(1, 0, 1, 0))
MRE <- data.frame(MRE_time, MRE_status)
sfit1 <- survfit(Surv(MRE_time, MRE_status)~1, data = MRE)
ggsurvplot(sfit1, data = MRE)`
```

Answer (score 2):

`MRE_status` should be numeric, not factor.

```r
MRE_time <- as.numeric(c(10, 20, 15, 30))
MRE_status <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
MRE <- data.frame(MRE_time, MRE_status)
sfit1 <- survfit(Surv(MRE_time, MRE_status)~1, data = MRE)
ggsurvplot(sfit1, data = MRE)
```

[image]